# How can I turn a local user into an administrator via the PowerShell command line?

Tags: windows, powershell, networking, explorer

PowerShell newcomer here, I'm writing a script which prepares newly installed PC's to be merged with my IT firms network. One task I'm having trouble with turning a local user account that I have created via PowerShell into a local administrator.

It is crucial that I use PowerShell to do this, but I haven't yet come across anything in my research. Also any help with understanding the functional aspect of the relationship between GPO's and PowerShell, or really anything that helps broaden PowerShell's capabilities which can be initiated via the command line (trying to make this script as self-sufficient and reusable as possible) would be greatly appreciated. Here's the script so far with corresponding tasks.

```
1.) $cn = [ADSI]"WinNT://Inquisition"    
$user = $cn.Create("User","Test")   
$user.SetPassword("P@ssword!")
$user.setinfo()    
$user.description = "TestUser"    
$user.SetInfo()

2.) Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter "name = 'Test'"  | Set-WmiInstance -Argument @{PasswordExpires = 0}

3.)?

4.) $Computername = "TEST1"

$sysinfo = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem $sysinfo.JoinDomainOrWorkGroup("AWS-TEST")

5.) netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off

6.) $AUSettings = (New-Object -com "Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate").Settings    
$AUSettings.NotificationLevel    
$ausettings.NotificationLevel = 1    
$ausettings.save()

7.) $path = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\'    
$name = 'start page'    
$value = 'http://www.blueprintcss.org/tests/parts/sample.html'    
Set-Itemproperty -Path $path -Name $name -Value $value

8.)?
```

1. Add a new user account named “Test” with a password of “P@ssw0rd!”
2. Set the password for account “Test” to never expire
3. Add user “Test” to the local Administrators security group
4. Set the computer name to be “TEST1” and the workgroup to “AWS-TEST”
5. Turn the Windows Firewall Off
6. Turn Windows Updates off and set to never check for updates
7. Set company website as the default webpage in Internet Explorer
8. Turn off the pop-up blocker in Internet Explorer

Comment: Did you try anything? Show us the code you have so far. Otherwise you won't get that much people who want to help you with this. That's just how it works here

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the post to show the script thus far. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Wow. I've been blocked from posting anything else for a day, because this question was downvoted. I'm completely new to stack, this is leaving a bitter taste in my mouth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar need once, except mine was to remove local admin rights. This was the core of what worked for me.... Since your new, make sure to predefine your variables for Domain name, Host name, and User. Hope this helps!

```
    $AdminGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$HostName/Administrators,group"
    $InUser = [ADSI]"WinNT://$DomainName/$User,user"
    $Admingroup.Add($InUser.Path)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I wasn't expecting such a direct answer. Just a couple last questions; By predefine you mean I'd do something like `$User = 'Test'` Before running something similar to what you showed me, correct? Also, how do I know what $Hostname and $DomainName should be defined as? I'm only really experienced in .NET, so this is all very new to me. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Yes, $User = 'Test' would be the way to do it if you're doing one offs, or you can import from a csv. Domain name would be the same as what you use to domain a computer, ie. 1dc.com if you're on a domain, otherwise you can basically disregard. Hostname would be the computername which can be input manually or via csv.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a single liner from https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/post/3297687

```
([ADSI]"WinNT://<computername>/Administrators,group").Add("WinNT://<domain>/<user>")
```